# Best practices for calling native code from Java

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jna

I intend to swap out some hotspots in my Java code for something native (perhaps C++, but still to be decided).  What are the modern choices for how to do this?  (I don't intend or want to port the whole application).

I might for example use:

- JNI
- JNA
- Spawn the native piece as a separate process, then communicate using:

  - TCP
  - UDP
  - shared memory
  - stdin/stdout
  - ZeroMQ..

I have complete freedom at this point of how I build this.  Is there a recommended best practice approach?

Comment: You're doing this for performance? The JIT compiler is pretty efficient nowadays. Native code should be used mostly for accessing system facilities that are not available in Java. You might be disappointed with the result.

Comment: Depends on the hotspot and the scope of the work to be processed.  CPU-intensive stuff should be handled pretty well by the JIT.  Large data is better farmed out to a scalable cloud-like service.  Your biggest gains, however would be from an algorithmic change of perspective.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question.  The best practice is going to be different depending on each "hot spot" your system has, and what alternatives you have available to you for native processing.

For example, in a Java application that I work with, we have several sections of graphics processing, including transformation from one format to another.  While third party Java libraries do exist and I've tested several, I haven't found one that is as efficient and accurate at transforming PDFs to TIFFs as a C++ library I access via JNI.  Why JNI over JNA?  Performance based on the version we tested with; the access via JNI code had a faster throughput.  This might not hold for all applications, but it did for my implementation.

Your hot spots could simply be an issue with your coding architecture and would simply need some investigation and refactoring within Java and not require any native replacement.

One application I refactored conducted several tasks in a procedural fashion.  Even multi-threading the entire procedure wasn't working.  I broke the procedure down into 8 different stages, and identified the bottleneck, which was then handled by a multi-threaded worker queue.  Now the system runs efficiently, and is still 100% Java.

Communication to non-Java applications is also dependent on what facilities exist for the non-Java application to accept that communication.  I've had scenarios where I've used `Runtime.exec()` to spawn a native process, dropped a data file in a folder for external processing, and made calls to Web Services.  The "native" solution really depends on (1) what your available native resources are, (2) which native resource is the best for handling this "hot spot" use case, and (3) what accessibility to said native resources is available.  And even then, refactoring your existing code might still be the best bet.

To reiterate: any given "hot spot" can be due to a number of factors, each requiring individual attention that a broad answer here cannot provide.  Your best bet is to identify each "hot spot", and evaluate them individually as to how best to optimize them; if necessary, then ask a "hot spot"-specific question for handling it.

Answer (score 0):

If the function is reasonably short (~milliseconds or less), in-process might be the only reasonable option. (When running a separate process, context switch latencies on each call may outweigh the execution time).

JNI is a portable API layer that is a de-facto standard; raw JNI is, however, not easy to use. JNA uses JNI under the hood, but it is higher level and easier to use, and quite popular. It might be your safest bet. You could also consider https://github.com/dejwk/janet (which I wrote); it also uses JNI under the hood, but I think it's even easier to use than JNA.